# K-theory of $\mathbb{RP}^{\infty}$

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology, topological-k-theory

what are the $K_0$ and $K_1$ group of $\mathbb{RP}^{\infty}$?

Any reference would be good enough.

Comment: Also posted in MO http://mathoverflow.net/questions/177994/k-theory-of-mathbbrp-infty

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atiyah%E2%80%93Segal_completion_theorem